# HP A5500 Routing to second firewall

Tags: routing, hp, vlan

My current network configuration is

[image]

All ISPs are 100/100Mbps and the PA-500 currently does all of the routing.

ISP 3 has offered an upgrade to 500Mbps however, the PA-500 it has a throughput of 250Mbps. Due to budget constraints, I won't be able to upgrade my firewall for a few months.

So my question is can I create a static route on my core switch to route a VLAN to ISP 3 to their provided Mikrotik router without compromising my existing network.

[image]

This VLAN is an open WiFi network which is already completely segregated from the rest of the network in the current configuration. DHCP and DNS are not an issue, I am just looking for some opinions as this is not something I would have ever considered before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks simply that you need to assign VLAN 3 to the port in the Core switch where ISP3's Microtik router is connected, and remove VLAN3 from the trunk between Core switch and Firewall.

You don't need to think about IP level routing here, since you already have a dedicated L2 VLAN for your purpose.

And no, this doesn't compromise your network since there is no IP layer modifications / firewalls needed.